# Which STL containers are main memory data structures?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I came across the term the term "main memory" data structures. For example [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011494316133) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610370/why-is-the-kd-tree-a-main-memory-structure) and [here](https://gateoverflow.in/148424/data-structure) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114923/will-b-trees-and-other-data-structures-become-obsolete-with-the-advent-of-solid). Googling did not give me a definite answer what that actually means. I got some reference that it means the data structures that are used to store in the persistent memory i.e. hard disk. If so, then as I have read binary trees are used store data on hard disks. If so, then std::map which uses binary tree will be one candidate for main memory data structure. What are other examples?

Comment: OSes are often developed using C and ASM which do not have STL containers. A bit unclear what you mean by _main memory data structures_.

Comment: _"I guess the term "main memory" data structures means..."_ why do you think this?

Comment: This is from googling "main memory" data structures. I could not find a definite answer about what is termed as "main memory" data structure.

Comment: A structure is just a structure. You can store a binary tree on post-it notes if you want to, or encode it in a piece of music that you can whistle.

Comment: So XY-problem then - where did you get the term _"main memory data structures"_ from and why do you need to define it?

Comment: All standard library containers are by default stored exclusively in memory, rather than (say) on disk.

Comment: @Richard Critten here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011494316133

Comment: The question is unclear, because because you essentially ask what c++ standard data structure fits requirements which "*Googling did not give [you] a definite answer what that actually means*". It's pretty much unanswearable given that "main memory" is not something common or well defined in c++ context.

Comment: ALL `STL` containers are main memory hosted. Main memory is basically `RAM` chips connected directly to the `CPU` (likely through a MMU). It is used in contrast to Disk storage where databases usually reside.

Answer (score 1):

First your understanding of "main memory" is wrong, main memory is used to refer to the system RAM, a hard drive is secondary storage. And then there are specialized on-chip caches that a program generally has little or no control over.

That being said, all of the STL containers are limited to being memory hosted, but depending on the OS this  can include having parts swapped out of main memory to disk as part of virtual memory, however that, too, a program has little or no control over. And such disk backing lasts only so long as the program is active, it is not persisted after termination.

And while b-trees are a good candidate for being persisted to disk backed storage a usual binary tree is not. In this context b-tree and binary tree are not the same thing.